# How to automatically add all Converters to a FormatterRegistry in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, converters

I have a Spring Boot 2.1.6 project that uses Spring's `Converter`s a lot (24 of them). All are annotated as `@Component`. Now I've added a `@EnableWebMvc` and have to add them to the `FormatterRegistry` via `registry.addConverter` in a `WebMvcConfigurer.addFormatters`

Can I have Spring find all of them *automatically* (they are all in the same separate package) and add them or do I have to manually add all 24 of them and change my `WebMvcConfigurer` every time I add a converter?

Comment: They all must have implemented Formatter interface right? Then you can simply do @Autowired List<Formatter> formatters;

Comment: @Rakesh: `Converter`, but yes, that helped. Please make it an answer so I can upvote and accept it. Or find the duplicate of this question. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have implemented the `Converter` interface and also annotated them with `@Component`, you can get them all by injecting them as a collection. `@Autowired List<Converter> converters;`

Answer (score 2):

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.format.Formatter;
import org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import java.util.List;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
List<Formatter> formatters;

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {

        formatters.forEach(registry::addFormatter);
    }
}
```